# Floating-point zero in C implementations (IEEE 754 invariants?)

Tags: c, numeric, ieee-754, zero

I have a following C expression (variables are 32-bit floats)

```
float result = (x1 - x0) * (y2 - y0) - (x2 - x0) * (y1 - y0)
```

Assuming that `x0==x1` and `y0==y1`, (and with `==` I mean binary representation identity), can I rely on the fact that the expression will necessarily evaluate to zero (as in, all bits of the float are set to 0)? In another words, can I assume that following invariants always hold?

```
memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(float) == 0 => memcmp(a-b, (uint32_t)0, sizeof(float)) == 0
0*a == 0.0
```

It is safe to assume that all values are finite numbers (no INFINITY or NaN).

Edit: As pointed out in the answers, multiplications with 0 can produce signed zeros. Can I still rely on the fact that the result of the expression will be equal to 0.0 using FP-comparison rules, i.e.:

```
(result == 0.0)
```

Edit 1: Replaced type casts by memcmp calls to illustrate the question better.

P.S. I am limiting my code to compliant C11 compilers only, in case it makes any difference. I am also willing to rely on **STDC_IEC_559** support if that will help my case.

Comment: Can we assume also that `y2 - y0` and `x2 - x0` will be finite?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: yes. If its not, I am ok with the results being undefined.

Comment: Which type are `a` and `b`? If they are not `uint32_t`, your code invokes undefined behaviour (violation of effective type rule). So anything is allowed by the standard. The same for `ZERO`

Comment: @Olaf: ok, then suppose that we have union {uint32_t ival, float fval} instead of type casting. Or a memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(float))==0. The idea is to say that a and b contains exactly the same binary representation. I am editing the question to make this more clear.

Comment: There is another problem: Are you asking about C floating point or about IEEE754 floating point?

Comment: I am asking about possible guarantees in the behaviour I am describing. If IEEE754 gives me this guarantee, I am willing to restrict my code only to IEEE754-compliant targets. If a target is not  IEEE754-compliant, I can always build in additional safety checks.

Answer (score 4):

Mentioning C11 just confuses your question because IEEE 754 is not required by any C standard.

That being said, just assuming IEEE 754 32 bit floating point numbers and making no assumptions on `x2` and `y2` (other than them not being infinite or NaN) you can't assume that all the bits of the result will be 0. IEEE 754 numbers have two zeroes, one negative and one positive and if the expression `(y2 - y0) - (x2 - x0)` is negative, the result of multiplying it with a zero will be a negative zero.

We can test it with this short example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    union {
        float f;
        uint32_t i;
    } foo;

    float a = 0;
    float b = -1;

    foo.f = a * b;
    printf("0x%x\n", foo.i);

    return 0;
}
```

The result (notice no optimizations since I don't want the compiler to be clever):

```
$ cc -o foo foo.c && ./foo
0x80000000
```

Oh, I just noticed that the second part of your question which you called "in other words" isn't actually in other words because it's a different question.

To start with:

```
(*(uint32_t*)(&a) == *(uint32_t*)(&b))
```

isn't equivalent to `a == b` for floating point because `-0 == 0`. And with that, the other part of the assumption falls apart because `-0 - 0` gives you `-0`. I'm not able to make any other subtraction of equal numbers generate a negative zero, but that doesn't mean it's not possible, I'm pretty sure that the standards don't enforce the same algorithm for subtraction on all implementations so a sign bit could sneak in there somehow.

Comment: Good catch with that "negative zero" thing. I would actually guess that the answer would be Yes (before reading yours).

Comment: Thanks, Art! You are right of course that mention of IEEE standard is a bit misleading. What I am most interested in is knowing whether I should build in additional identity checks on common hardware, with common C11 compilers, or whether I can safely skip the checks. The signed zero comment is very helpful! I would be ok with doing FP comparison to 0 instead of 'zero bit-pattern' zero. Would that be safe?

Comment: @MrMobster Your safest bet to compare a floating point number to zero is `a == 0.0`. This will work regardless if a is negative or positive.

Comment: It's worth to note that according to C11 `§6.10.8.3 Conditional feature macros - ... __STDC_IEC_559__ The integer constant 1, intended to indicate conformance to the specifications in annex F (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic).` and C11 `§Annex F.2 ... The float type matches the IEC 60559 single format. ...`. The IEC 60559 specification is identical to IEEE 754-2008.

Comment: The cast-lines actually invoke UB. Anything can happen. From the standard's view, **any** behaviour is legal.